# $_GET not passed in one of my htaccess rules with QSA flag

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with one of my url rewriting rules. I have the following rules in my htaccess:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^bands.html$ /groupes.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bands/([0-9a-zA-Z,-]+).html$ /groupes.php?groupe_nom_rewrite=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^bands/([0-9a-zA-Z,-]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z,-]+).html$ /albums.php?groupe_nom_rewrite=$1&album_nom_rewrite=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^labels.html$ /labels.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^labels/([0-9a-zA-Z,-]+).html$ /labels.php?label_nom_rewrite=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

The first four rules work correctly, but the last one doesn't: the parameter `label_nom_rewrite` is lost during redirection. I have the `QSA` flag and similar rules before work well (e.g. in the second one, I have the parameter `groupe_nom_rewrite` as a `$_GET` variable, as expected).

Why is that? And how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

The mod_negotiation module may be turned on which means when it sees a request that starts with `/labels/`, it will automatically send the request to `/labels.php` and bypass mod_rewrite.

Comment: Thanks a lot that's it! But why did I have this behaviour on this one rule and not the previous ones?

Comment: @OuberThat because you don't have a `bands.php` file. And labels.html getting handled by mod_negotiation would appear no different than mod_rewrite handling it.